How to make a QT Popup close when clicking outside of it?
When I open a PySide6/Qt6 Popup Window the user can't click outside the popup to close it. The only way I found is to press ESC, clicks the window titlebar or switches to a different application, which isn't very intuitive and user friendly imho.
Is there a way to make it close by clicking outside the popup?
Or do I need to use a different flag, component or something?
The goal is to have a Textinput Field which shows some search results while the user types.
I made a small test implementation in python where the Popup opens by clicking on a button to show how the popup will close only when the user presses ESC, clicks the window titlebar or switches to a different application.
I tried PySide6 as shown below, but also tried Qt6 with the same result.
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QListView, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QDialog
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QStringListModel
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Button Example")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 600)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        button = QPushButton("Open List View")
        button.clicked.connect(self.show_popup)
        layout.addWidget(button)


    def show_popup(self):
        dialog = QDialog(self)
        dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowType.Popup)
        dialog.setWindowTitle("List View Popup")
        dialog.setModal(True)
        dialog.resize(300, 400)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        list_view = QListView()
        
        model = QStringListModel()
        model.setStringList(["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"])
        list_view.setModel(model)
        
        layout.addWidget(list_view)
        dialog.setLayout(layout)
        dialog.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


I cannot reproduce at least on Linux (clicking outside of the popup closes it) as it's expected to do (as also noted in the documentation). What OS and version are you using? Also, consider doing tests with: 1. QWidget instead of QDialog; 2. try using dialog.open() instead of show().

oh great, I'm on macOS 15.1.1, tried on two Macs with that OS version, same behaviour. Tried on Win 11 now, and yeah it works the way I want it. dialog.open() didn't help, but QWidgt instead of QDialog seems to work.
I will try to use that in my app. Thanks.

macOS has its own quirkiness's, which often create issues or unexpected behaviors with third party toolkits (especially those aimed for multi platform consistencies). QDialog is basically a QWidget with the Qt::Dialog flag already set upon creation, so it should not change much. But, after looking up the sources, I see that setModal() is slightly different than QWidget's setWindowModality(), and setVisible() also add more code that also depends on the OS. Since you don't seem to actually use QDialog aspects, using QWidget would be more appropriate in any case, with the difference »

» of the Esc key that needs implementation through a keyPressEvent() override (or an event filter). Note that, since that widget seems to be only intended as temporary, you should also ensure it's deleted once it's closed (otherwise it will be kept in memory), so you may consider setting the WA_DeleteOnClose attribute. I'd write an answer, but since I cannot test on macOS it would be based on guesses and assumptions, so I suggest you to answer your own question (by pressing the related button on this page), explaining what you did and providing a related MRE.

I found that QListView also has the non-closable behaviour like QDialog. I tried QListView with all three WindowModality Flags, each has a slightly different behaviour, but they all won't close.
In that minimal implementation I was able to use a QListView as the popup, and put a mouseReleaseEvent into MainWindow and hide the popup from there. But in my full implementation the mouseRelease Event won't trigger on any of the components. I'm still experimenting to find the cause to this.

QListView is a scroll area, they handle mouse events differently as they only receive those generated on the viewport. You must use a QWidget as parent.

It seems this is a bug in the macOS QT?
Anyway I solved this by installing an eventFilter on the popup. This is the code that fixed it for me:
def eventFilter(self, obj: QObject, event: QEvent) -> bool:
    logger.debug(f"[TagCompleterPopup] - eventFilter - Event type: {event.type()} - type: {type(event)}")

    if isinstance(event, QMouseEvent):
        mouse_event = QMouseEvent(event)
        if not self.rect().contains(mouse_event.pos()):
            self.hide()
            return True
        
    return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


For completeness (it was only written in comments), you should also add that this is only necessary for QDialog, as it works as expected with QWidget. If you're sticking with QDialog due to the Esc key, it would be far better to just create a simple QWidget subclass overriding keyPressEvent instead of using an event filter (which receives all events). For what's worth, this is even a case for which a brute monkey patching could be acceptable (with dialog being a QWidget): def maybeClose(e): if e.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Escape: dialog.close() and then dialog.keyPressEvent = maybeClose

pressing ESC always closed the popup, but mouse clicks outside of the popup didn't.

You probably didn't get what I meant. You're using QDialog, but the only reason you seem to be using it (at least based on your code) is to take advantage of the "close on Esc". Since you're facing a more important issue in compatibility, and the "Esc" aspect is much easier (and consistent) to solve, you should then not use QDialog, but QWidget, either with the "patching" suggested above, or through a subclass. Besides, you could've subclassed QDialog to begin with, but the point remains: you don't seem to be using it for the real purposes and primary features that class offers.

In my full implementation I use a QListView. afaik that's a QWidget and I faced the same problem there.

I already explained that as well, please read more carefully what's being written to you. QListView is a scroll area, they handle mouse events very differently. All widgets (including "windows") are QWidgets, but it's not that simple; for instance, the inheritance of QListView is: QListView»QAbstractItemView»QAbstractScrollArea»QFrame»QWidget»QObject. Specifically, the QAbstractScrollArea implementation is what prevents what QWidget normally would (close on click outside of the geometry). Besides, you said yourself that using QWidget instead of QDialog worked, wasn't that a sufficient clue?
